# Migrating TFVC to Git wrong hierarchy on TFVC

Tags: git, branch, hierarchy, tfvc, git-tfs

We have a Problem in a migrate existing TFVC to GIT using the GIT-TFS, we have already an existing project in AzureDevOps, that has already created some branches.

The structure is `DEV -> Main -> ProdRel`

But the Hierarchy is wrong, is set as: `DEV -> Main` and `ProdRel -> Main`.

As part of the problem we have some ongoing work between Main a ProdRel that is not going to be at ProdRel soon.

I tried to many things but at this moment I feel is not possible to migrate to GIT in a clean way, because when I set the hierarchy well and tried to migrate it doesn't recognize the parent changes and rise some conflicts.

##### Things tested

- Change the hierarchy to the correct one on TFVC, and migrated to GIT using GIT-TFS: I have a problem because when I migrate the ProdRel Branch it doesn't know who is the parent of the changes, because it has 2 parents.

##### Other options

Migrate TFVC to GIT and from GIT to TFVC, I didn't find how to migrate from GIT to TFVC.

Is possible to do this?

Thanks
Kind Regards

Comment: Can you clarify the problem you have if you migrate with the existing hierarchy? The hierarchy is a TFVC thing. Git doesn't care about hierarchy, you can merge any branch in to any other branch. If you want to enforce a hierarchy post migration, then this is a purely process thing. Git won't prevent merges from any branch to any other branch

Comment: The problem is when I'm trying to do a cherry picking on the GIT repository is not able to do, because it doesn't recognize the changeset between Main and ProdRel, and as I know , seems the problem comes because the hierarchy was not set correctly in the past and now there's not a trace between Main changeset and ProdRel. On the other hand I modified the hierarchy before execute the migration between TFVC to GIT and is requiring the root changeset.